# Swift: Picker new View

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, picker

For each Struct i get the error (Invalid redeclaration of 'GameOneView'). Also at the bracket of the ZStack i get this error (Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate) Additionally, my third error is at the Label.(Use of unresolved identifier 'Label')

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var games = ["Game One", "Game Two", "Game Three", "Game Four", "Game Five"]
    @State var selectedGame = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView
        {
            ZStack
            {
                Form
                {
                    Section(header: Label("You selected:", systemImage: "gamecontroller"))
                    {
                        NavigationLink(destination: gameFinderV3(game: $games[selectedGame]) ) { Text(games[selectedGame]) }
                    }
                }
                
                
                Picker(selection: $selectedGame, label: Text(""))
                    { ForEach(0 ..< games.count) { index in Text(games[index]) } }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("All Games"))
            
        }
        
        
    }
}





struct gameFinderV3: View
{

@Binding var game: String

var body: some View {
    
    
    return Group
    {
        if      game == "Game One"
        {
            GameOneView()
        }
        else if game == "Game Two"
        {
            GameTwoView()
        }
        else if game == "Game Three"
        {
            GameThreeView()
        }
        else if game == "Game Four"
        {
            GameFourView()
        }
        else if game == "Game Five"
        {
            GameFiveView()
        }
        else
        {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
    
}

struct GameOneView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameOneView")}}
    struct GameTwoView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameTwoView")}}
    struct GameThreeView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameThreeView")}}
    struct GameFourView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFourView")}}
    struct GameFiveView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFiveView")}}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here, it was not Easy Task:**

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var games = ["Game One", "Game Two", "Game Three", "Game Four", "Game Five"]
    @State var selectedGame = 0

    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView
        {
            ZStack
            {
                Form
                {
                    Section(header: Label("You selected:", systemImage: "gamecontroller"))
                    {
                        NavigationLink(destination: gameFinder(game: games[selectedGame]) ) { Text(games[selectedGame]) }
                    }
                }
                

                Picker(selection: $selectedGame, label: Text(""))
                { ForEach(0 ..< games.count) { index in Text(games[index]) } }

            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("All Games"))
            
        }
        

    }
}

func gameFinder(game: String) -> AnyView
{

    if      game == "Game One"
    {
        return AnyView(GameOneView())
    }
    else if game == "Game Two"
    {
        return AnyView(GameTwoView())
    }
    else if game == "Game Three"
    {
        return AnyView(GameThreeView())
    }
    else if game == "Game Four"
    {
        return AnyView(GameFourView())
    }
    else if game == "Game Five"
    {
        return AnyView(GameFiveView())
    }
    else
    {
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}



struct GameOneView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameOneView")}}
struct GameTwoView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameTwoView")}}
struct GameThreeView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameThreeView")}}
struct GameFourView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFourView")}}
struct GameFiveView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFiveView")}}
```

**Version: 2.1.0**

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var games = ["Game One", "Game Two", "Game Three", "Game Four", "Game Five"]
    @State var selectedGame = 0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView
        {
            ZStack
            {
                Form
                {
                    Section(header: Text("You selected:"))
                    {
                        NavigationLink(destination: gameFinderV3(game: $games[selectedGame]) ) { Text(games[selectedGame]) }
                    }
                }
                


                   
                    Picker(selection: $selectedGame, label: Text(""))
                        { ForEach(0 ..< games.count) { index in Text(games[index]) } }
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle(Text("All Games"))
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    
    
   
    
    struct gameFinderV3: View
    {
    
    @Binding var game: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        return Group
        {
            if      game == "Game One"
            {
                GameOneView()
            }
            else if game == "Game Two"
            {
                GameTwoView()
            }
            else if game == "Game Three"
            {
                GameThreeView()
            }
            else if game == "Game Four"
            {
                GameFourView()
            }
            else if game == "Game Five"
            {
                GameFiveView()
            }
            else
            {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        
         
        
        
    }
    
}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    struct GameOneView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameOneView")}}
    struct GameTwoView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameTwoView")}}
    struct GameThreeView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameThreeView")}}
    struct GameFourView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFourView")}}
    struct GameFiveView: View { var body: some View {Text("GameFiveView")}}
```

[image]

Comment: Vielen Dank Omid. Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, I get an error at the Navigation Link. (Cannot call value of non-function type 'NavigationLink<Text, AnyView>')

Comment: I add Version 2.0.0 of codes! try that and see if it works!

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but if i just copy and paste it there are multiple errors.

Comment: I saw your screenshot, it was because of Label, I think you are not using a apple device, or something like that, how ever I removed that Label out, and replace it with Text, Now it should working for you, in the fact there was and is error from your side, you could run V1 even without problem, how ever it seems you are not using right device or software.

Comment: I am using xCode 11 and a Apple MacBook Pro. Maybe you could send a ZIP File? Because i stell get the erros and i am a bit confused because it works on your computer but not on mine.

Comment: LoL! See what I told you! the codes were correct even from version 1, you are not up to date! my Xcode version: Version 12.1 (12A7403)

Comment: Danke dir und liebe Grüße nach Österreich. Es funktioniert alles. Vielen lieben Dank

Comment: Aber Gerne, Viel Spaß mit SwiftUI